# Why did Donald Pierce need Laura?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the movie *Logan*, Donald Pierce spends much time and energy trying to capture Laura. In retrospect, had Donald Pierce simply not worried about Laura, he would still be alive and still have his super weapon.

**Why was it important for him to capture Laura?**

Comment: He mentioned at one point she is a company patent running around. If someone got their hands on her they may be able to reverse engineer their work and branch off on their own procedures. His anticipation was to snag her up and dispose of her internally. Not necessarily die in the process. Plus, he probably had a boss and orders he was supposed to follow. Just the way it goes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**She was a liability as well as stolen company property and needed to be brought in for decommissioning.**

### Weapon-X is dead, long live Weapon-X

If you recall, the Weapon-X program was declared a failure and shut down, so all of its current subjects were to be decommissioned and disposed of. This was the main reason that nurse Gabriela and the other staff conducted the mass breakout with the clone-mutant children.

Transigen wanted to concentrate on their new direction for Weapon-X; X-24.

### Broken Arrow

Laura (along with the other mutant-clone kids) were declared as unsafe and compromised, a broken arrow so to speak. Not only that, but they were considered as "stolen company property", needing to be retrieved. It was Pierce's imperative to bring her in to ensure the safety of the public, as well as the safety of secrets which the Weapon-X program had.

### Logan, the troublemaker

It all fell apart when Logan (and Professor X) were thrown into the equation. Retrospect is absolutely moot in situations like these; Pierce was not expecting to have so much trouble bringing Laura in. He seemed pretty at ease and confident in his and his team's ability to capture Laura (after all, they have had a very good success rate to date). Logan was having none of it though. Things simply escalated:

- At first Pierce was just following trails and leads
- Bumps into Logan, but only coincidentally as Logan was seen with nurse Gabriela
- Approaches Logan when he realises Laura must be harboured at the hideout
- All hell breaks loose

He doesn't have the benefit of hindsight, unfortunately.

### Pierce is just doing his job

Pierce is a soldier (of sorts). He's under the employ of Transigen; whether he and his Reavers are mercenaries or fully employed by Transigen is unknown. He's been given the order or job to bring in Laura and wrangle up the rest of the children. He has no reason to stop even when things got really complicated and dangerous; especially given that since he's still around, he has a very good success rate.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two good reasons :

1. **Laura is an investment**

   It took lots of time, money and effort to create someone with her powers and it seems that her skills only grew over the time when she was running away. You don't simply let such a thing go away, if there is a chance that you can still benefit from it: you can somehow mind control her, wait few years and impregnate (and have potentially even better mutant) or, in worst case scenario simply recover samples of her flesh and precious Adamantium.
2. **Laura is a witness**

   Laura has been brought up in facility where she was treated as a thing. She and her friends were tortured and experimented upon, which resulted in turning innocent child into weapon of mass destruction. Joe Public wouldn't be too happy if such soapy story would leak to media.
   On the other hand, it's a proof that the government is still dabbling in the whole mutant thingy, that was such a danger to us all just few years ago.

Comment: If 1 was true, why does he have to kill the other kids? If 2 was a concern, why didn't Laura and the caretaker go the media at any point?

Comment: he doesn't try to kill the kids only capture them. Yes, they are shot at but not executed and eventual deaths are accidental rather than purposeful. If he wanted them dead he could bomb that little camp of theirs that his drone found. 2. Because it's better to go to the media when you are safe from the immediate harm.

Comment: 3. Laura is physical evidence